# How to detect approaching to camera on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-camera

How to detect approaching object to iPhone? I'm trying to detect with camera and calculating brightness but I have problems to calibrate for different ambient light. I saw this solved in some apps for detecting push ups, when camera detect when I get close to camera with my finger on 2 cm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about using a proximity sensor?

Comment: you could use edge detection through kernel convolutions. if there are many soft edges, it's probably because something is too close to the camera to be be focussed correctly.

Comment: Proximity sensor doing a job but have a bad side with black screen, it spoils the user experience.